# How to pass value of a function into a async.waterfall function

Tags: javascript, node.js, async.js

I have a problem with my code. I want to select from a Mysql table and considering the result, change it and update that table again. Problem is, the code do this asynchronous and it won't work properly (it do all SELECT first and all of UPDATE after). So I used async.js to get the job done, but still not working. Because I cant pass the Selected value out of caller callback. So it is not possible to pass it to next callback via async.waterfall. Any ideas?

```
async.waterfall([

    function (callback) {

        queryBuilder.selectAgent(connection, id, (agent) => {
            // Here is the PROBLEM! I can't pass agent out of this
        });

        // Here agent will be undefined
        callback(null, agent);
    },

    function (agent, callback) {

        if (agent) {
            // Some change on agent and pass it to next callback
        }

        callback(null, agent);
    },

    function (agent, callback) {

        queryBuilder.updateAgent(connection, id, agent);

        callback(null);
    },

],

function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;

})
```

Comment: Why not call `callbackl(null, agent)` in the `selectAgent` callback ? Like this         `queryBuilder.selectAgent(connection, id, (agent) => callback(null, agent));` NOTE: I do not know about the lifetime of the `agent` object!

Comment: Because it cause my first place problem! If I call callback(null, agent) inside of queryBuilder.selectAgent(), all of SELECT will execute first and all of UPDATE after it and I want them to run this way => SELECT, UPDATE, SELECT, UPDATE, ...

Answer (score 0):

You need change in `updateAgent` method to check the previous value and add new data to it OR you can check for update of any particular item first and gather them to update the field once.